# Stop excessive logging of SUDO & SSH logins to syslog & wtmp for a specific user account

Tags: ssh, systemd, pam, wtmp

I have a monitoring server (‘ClusterControl’) which  uses a regular user account to login using an *‘interactive shell’* and runs some sudo maintenance commands.

This account logs-in via an SSH Key (passwordless) 4 times per minute it seems.

The `/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/syslog` fill up with thousands of login and sudo entries.

Three problems arise:

1. Syslog auditing fails since `/var/log/syslog` is un-usable without passing it through various `grep` filters to mask out login entries.
2. System disk runs out of space. The files `/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/syslog` get very large in size very quickly and cause serious storage space issues.
3. The `last` account auditing command effectively, experiences a denial of service since it is rendered un-usable as the serviceaccount username is logged and displayed thousands of times and other account logins are impossible to see.

###### Question

How can I exclude this user account from being logged?

P.S. I have tried adding a PAM entry of `systemd  [success=ok default=1]  pam_succeed_if.so user in username` in the various pam files located in `/etc/pam.d` folder as some articles have directed but it has not worked.

I’m not sure which file to use and what the correct syntax should be.

`/var/log/syslog` shows the ssh username login logged by ‘systemd’ at the beginning of the log line.

The server is Ubuntu 18.04

##### EDIT

ClusterControl runs an *interactive shell* using `ssh -t` when it logs in as stated by one of the company’s System Support Engineers in a blog post [here](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/wtmp-log-rotation-settings-sudo-user-clustercontrol). However, their suggestion is merly to enable more frequent log rotations.

Comment: You need to give more information on how you connect and execute commands via ssh. Generally, when you execute a command like `ssh server command`, no login shell is executed on the server, therefore nothing is recorded into /var/log/wtmp.

Comment: @xhienne I only know that ClusterControl runs an _interactive shell_ using `ssh -t` when it logs in as stated by one of the company’s System Support Engineers in a blog post [here](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/wtmp-log-rotation-settings-sudo-user-clustercontrol). However, their suggestion is merly to enable more frequent log rotation.

Comment: I don't know ClusterControl but the way it works is the root of your problems. As I said, `ssh server command` doesn't log in wtmp. But they probably chose to `echo command | ssh -t server` or something similar, so that they can use `sudo`. Remove the `-t` and your problem is gone. IMO, your question is specific to this commercial product ClusterControl.

Comment: @xhienne 2 things:
1) Am I to understand that it is possible for the product developers to remove the `ssh -t` method and still use sudo?  

2) In the absence of a solution from the product developers, my question still stands. How can I exclude this and only this user from being logged to wtmp? There must be a way I believe.

Comment: 1. Quoting the page you linked to: "On Debian/Ubuntu system, **sudo user does not need to acquire tty as it defaults to have no “requiretty”** configured. However, **ClusterControl defaults to append -t** flag if it detects the SSH user as a non-root user." => "ClusterControl defaults to" suggests this can be disabled. 2. Yes, your question is legitimate and has probably a solution on the server side, that's why it is still opened, waiting for someone to answer ;-)

Comment: This is an old and known issue with ClusterControl: https://support.severalnines.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360014883043--var-log-wtmp-log-file-growth-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 choices.

### TL;DR

#### 1. Syslog Filters

Using **rsyslog** ***filters*** is by far the quickest solution but not as comprehensive as using **PAM**.

At the top of your *rsyslog* default conf file, add the keywords you wish to filter on and the filter command. In this case, the filter command is delete ('`~`').

```bash
$ vi /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
:msg, contains, "clustercontrol" ~
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root" ~
:msg, contains, "Removed session" ~
```

#### 2. Manage Log Files

While I managed to stop thousands of logs being recorded per day in `syslog` & `auth.log` there didn't seem to be a way to stop logging the service account SSH logins from clustercontrol to the `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/lastlog` files.

For this, we use **logrotate** (See below).

### Logrotate

#### Lastlog + wtmp

Even setting `noupdate` or `nowtmp` directives for `pam_lastlog.so` globally, had no effect on my system so I simply made sure to compress and rotate these logs regularly using the logrotate config below.

The below config will rotate the logs monthly or every 200Mb, whichever comes first. Logs will be compressed and retained for a maximum of 12 months:

```bash
$ vi /etc/logrotate.conf
# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 12
    size 200M
    compress
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 12
    size 200M
    compress
}
```

### Using PAM

#### PAM Debug

The first step to understanding what was going on was to enable debug messages. The problem was that on my Ubuntu 18.04, the pam debug messages were not being logged - until I *explicitly* told *rsyslog* which file to record debug messages in using:

```bash
$ vi /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
*.debug           /var/log/debug.log

$ service rsyslog restart
```

#### pam_succeed_if.so

This is the pam module we will use to write conditional tests using pam.
The documentation is a little in-complete, dry and not very verbose on just how the rules work and what all the directives do. After reading a dozen or so articles, here's what I managed to piece together:

#### Understand who's doing the logging

Inside `/var/log/auth.log` you'll see the log messages we wish to stop for this user account:

> *Mar 17 13:05:27 dev1 sshd[18833]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user clustercontrol by (uid=0)*

> *Mar 17 13:04:25 dev1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by clustercontrol(uid=0)*

From the above logs we can tell that **pam_unix.so** is the pam authentication module doing the logging. It's being called by two separate services **sshd** and **sudo**.

The pam [type token](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/x115.html) tells pam what type of authentication is to be used for this module. In this case, ***session*** which are things that should be done before and/or after the user is authenticated.

##### **Responsible PAM Config**

So lets find the pam module `pam_unix.so` responsible for these logs in our system's configuration.

```bash
$ cd /etc/pam.d

$ grep 'pam_unix.so' * -in
common-account:17:account       [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
common-auth:17:auth     [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
common-password:25:password     [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
common-session:29:session       required        pam_unix.so 
common-session-noninteractive:30:session        required        pam_unix.so 
runuser:5:session               required        pam_unix.so
```

From above, we can see that `pam_unix.so` module for  ':session' is in the file `common-session` on line **#29**.

###### IMPORTANT

1. Find the line in */etc/pam.d/**sshd*** that includes the `common-session` file and add your custom `pam_succeed_if.so` statement just ***before*** it.
2. Now do ***almost*** exactly the same for the */etc/pam.d/***sudo**** file, but here our custom rule syntax is a little different.

#### Custom PAM Rules

##### **Sequence is Important**

Just before our `pam_unix.so` rules are run from the `@include common-session` file, we place our `pam_succeed.so` module rule.

##### **sshd rule**

```bash
$ grep -in include /etc/pam.d/sshd
5:@include common-auth
15:@include common-account
29:@include common-session
32:# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
56:@include common-password
```

**Line 29** in our case.

```bash
$ vi /etc/pam.d/sshd +29
session [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet service in sshd user = clustercontrol
# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session
```

Its easier if we read the rules from back to front:

We check if a user named *clustercontrol* (`user = clustercontrol`) is authenticated by **sshd** (`service in sshd`) then this rule matches and we run the directive (`quiet`) which makes logging *quiet*.

The part `[success=done`  means, if you get a match to this rule, we're `done` so skip processing the next rules, or skip over the **next** rule in the pam stack.

This effectively stops sshd logging for this user.

##### **sudo rule**

For this I added line **#6** to */etc/pam.d/sudo* :

```bash
$ vi /etc/pam.d/sudo
:set number 

  1 #%PAM-1.0
  2 
  3 session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
  4 session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
  5 
  6 session [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = clustercontrol
  7 @include common-auth
  8 @include common-account
  9 @include common-session-noninteractive
```

> session [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = clustercontrol

Our syntax is a little different here. Sudo generally runs commands as the ***root*** user (unless special directives tell it otherwise). On unix like systems that's ***user 0***.

So our custom rule is saying, if the *sudo* command is run in the context of user with uid 0 by the remote user (*ruser*), in our case this is *clustercontrol*, then be *quiet* with logging and we're *done* so skip any further rules for this user of type *session* authentication.

**NB**
Don't forget to comment out the ****.debug*** line in */etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf* and restart the service with `$ service rsyslog restart`.