# How to suppress PAM audit logs for RHEL8?

Tags: linux, rhel, pam, linux-audit

I have a system that is getting a ton of audit traffic for a particular account we will call 'redacted'. The logs are showing this account executing the su command. My first instinct was to check the rules in `etc/audit/rules.d` and disable any rules having to do with `su` and to add a rule suppressing logging for that account. I was still getting these logs so I wiped out the audit rules to have a blank slate.  (`auditctl -l No Rules`)

I was still seeing these logs so my question is are these coming from the PAM modules and is there a way to suppress them?

```
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1652729209.332:1763023): pid=375379 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_rootok acct="redacted" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1652729210.442:1763024): pid=375600 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_rootok acct="redacted" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1652729210.443:1763025): pid=375600 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_succeed_if acct="redacted" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1652729210.446:1763026): pid=375600 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_rootok acct="redacted" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=USER_START msg=audit(1652729210.462:1763027): pid=375600 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_lastlog,pam_umask,pam_xauth acct="redacted" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

Comment: Try running `auditctl -D` followed by `service auditd restart`, and make sure `/etc/audit/audit.rules` is empty as well if you truly want no audit rules.

Comment: I did run `auditctl -D` before restarting the service but I did not check  `/etc/audit/audit.rules`. I can check next time. I figured if `auditctl -l` is showing no output it was cleared successfully.

Comment: Can you fix the underlying issue, stopping whatever it is from calling `su` so often? I would suggest that this is a bad architectural design and if the process needs to call `su` this often it's probably running as the wrong account

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224370/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637227/117549 as potentially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to suppress these outputs by adding rules to supress the message by type. For example `-a never,exclude -F msgtype=USER_AUTH`